# MONTHS_BETWEEN Function

Tags: oracle

Can someone help me understand the working of Oracle Months_Between Function?
If I query `select MONTHS_BETWEEN('02-28-2015', '01-28-2015')`
I get an integer value of 1 but if  I query 
`select MONTHS_BETWEEN('02-28-2015', '01-29-2015')` I get 0.96.

Comment: you went from Jan 29th -> Feb 28th. That's less than a month. And month math is always a hideous stinking mess, because a month doesn't have a constant size. it's 28,29,30,31.

Comment: @MarcB if thats the case why do I get 1 for select MONTHS_BETWEEN('02-28-2015', '01-31-2015')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

Note - the "31 day month" convention may cause weird results around month-ends. Consider:

```
select months_between(date '2016-07-02', date '2016-07-01') as one_day,
       months_between(date '2016-07-01', date '2016-06-30') as another_day
from dual;

   ONE_DAY ANOTHER_DAY
---------- -----------
.032258065  .064516129

1 row selected.
```

As if June had 31 days. It doesn't, but `months_between` treats it as though it did.

Comment: Thanks!!...just wanted to make sure that I am not missing anything.So the function is indeed not perfect in dealing with 30,31,28 day month ends.

Comment: Define "perfect". The function does exactly what the documentation is telling it should....

Comment: @hetOrakel - perhaps there is no perfect calculation, but an alternative that would make definite sense (and one could argue, more than the 31 day convention) would be the actual day convention. Each day would be equal to 1/n months where n is the number of days in the month that day belongs to.

Comment: Haha, nice one. One could write such function, because the nr of days of each month is exactly known. But hey, the programmers at Oracle picked a convention and built and documented a function. When someone wants something else he/she should write his own... The OP(?) asked for a clarification and got it. Your answer is OK. The function is OK. Maybe not suitable for his use-case but that should he decide. (Edit/BTW I never use this function...)

Comment: Came across a similar situation, ```MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE('2026-02-28'), DATE('2024-01-30')), MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE('2026-02-28'), DATE('2024-01-31'))``` would return 24.935 and 25 respectively. So for three days x < y < z, months_between(x, z) < months_between(y, z). This is not desirable as a distance measure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with just trying to determine the number of months in a set of months and don't care about the days. I find myself in this situation often... You can do a bit of date manipulation which is rather reliable for determining the number of months in a set of months. Say for instance Jul - Sep while starting with dates.

Thusly:

```
WITH MONTHS AS (
SELECT
   SYSDATE     DATE_ONE
,  SYSDATE+57  DATE_TWO
FROM DUAL
)


SELECT
m.*
,TO_CHAR(m.DATE_ONE,'MON') START_MONTH
,TO_CHAR(m.DATE_TWO,'MON') END_MONTH
,MONTHS_BETWEEN(m.DATE_TWO,m.DATE_ONE)                                     UNEXPECTED_RESULT
,MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(m.DATE_TWO),LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(m.DATE_ONE,-1)))  EXPECTED_RESULT
FROM MONTHS m
;
```